Installing ProteoWizard on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I want to install ProteoWizard (Docker/Wine 64 bit version) on my Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64.
Therfore, I have to install Docker engine on my PC. However, I read that one should be carefull about ufw (firewall) when installing Docker engine (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/). Should I enable ufw or disable it¿
Moreover, When I chose the software (Docker/Wine 64 bit ) and clicked DOWNLOAD on ProteoWizard Download page (https://proteowizard.sourceforge.io/download.html), I was redirected to another page (https://hub.docker.com/r/chambm/pwiz-skyline-i-agree-to-the-vendor-licenses). It shows:
*one Docker Pull Command: docker pull chambm/pwiz-skyline-i-agree-to-the-vendor-licenses

two other commands (examples):


docker run -it --rm -e WINEDEBUG=-all -v /your/data:/data chambm/pwiz-skyline-i-agree-to-the-vendor-licenses wine msconvert /data/file.raw

2.docker run -it --rm -e WINEDEBUG=-all -v /your/data:/data chambm/pwiz-skyline-i-agree-to-the-vendor-licenses wine SkylineCmd --dir=/data/Skyline-files --in=.sky --import-file=.raw --chromatogram-products --chromatogram-file=.tsv.
Should I run the Docker pull command directly without dowloading Docker engine¿
Do you have an idea¿
Thank you
